# Interface for result with unknown fields

Tags: angular, typescript

Given a JSON response like

```
{
    "item1": ["A", "B", "C" ],
    "item2": [ "a", "b"],
    // ...
}
```

What is an interface definition where the fields (`"item1"`, `"item2"`, ...) are dynamic, that is neither their name, nor their count is known in advanced? I tried

```
interface Foo {
  item1: string[]; 
  item2: string[];
}
```

which is obviously wrong since it is not dynamic.

I hope this is enough context, otherwise, what I want is to return a result of type `Map<string, Set<string>>` from an [HttpClient.get()](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get). And I am under the impression that I first have to give an interface (using simple types and arrays) and then I have to the simple types to `Map<string, Set<string>>`.

```
this.httpClient
  .post<Foo>("http://localhost:50080/Foo", ["foo"])
  .map(f => new Map<string, Set<string>>([]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an [index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.9.4) (see also in the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)). The correct syntax is

```
export interface Foo {
  [key: string]: string[];
}
```

It means your key is a string, and its value is an array of strings.

You also can create a type and "lock" the keys like so

```
type Items = 'item1' | 'item2';

export interface Foo {
  [key in Items]: string[];
}
```